# Why ArrayCollection.addItem is slower than Array.push in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex

I had a code that added a bunch of objects into an ArrayCollection (with ArrayCollection.addItem()). Initially I didn't notice much of a difference in the response time of this code.

But as the number of objects added into the ArrayCollection increased, the routine took longer to respond.

I had to drop ArrayCollection and use Array instead and resorted to pushing (Array.push()) elements into the array.

I couldn't understand why this was happening. What is the difference? Can someone reason this out?

Comment: Array is native to ActionScript (like a primitive). ArrayCollection is just a Flex wrapper around Array with added functionality.

Comment: If you show code it would help.  Have you done formal performance tests?

Comment: If it helps, you can create a new ArrayCollection after the Array is fully populated by passing the Array into the constructor. 
If I had to guess why there's a performance difference, assuming you aren't doing anything else to cause it, I suppose it'd be due to events even though there may not be anything listening for change events.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This confused me too at first when dealing with multiple items. RIAstar has already touched the issue: Array is a primitive, just like int is a primitive. ArrayCollection is a instantiable class as part of the flex framework, with many more features. Because it's a class, it gets slower as the data with it gets bigger, because of the overhead and the processing required of all the class extensions of ArrayCollection.

The main additions of ArrayCollection is that you can [add events](http://blog.flexexamples.com/2008/05/14/determining-when-an-arraycollection-changes-in-flex/) to them, that you can't on Arrays. For example, when you add, or change, or remove an item in the ArrayCollection, it will dispatch any event that you added through the addEventListener function.

Also, ArrayCollection has a lot more useful item management functions, like [filtering](http://weblog.mrinalwadhwa.com/2007/07/07/flex-tip-of-the-day-filterfunction-for-real-time-filtering-of-data/), [sorting](http://www.spltech.co.uk/blog/adobe-flex/client-data/sorting-an-arraycollection-using-sortfield), and adding, getting and removing items at locations in the collection rather than their registered indexes.

Choosing between Array and ArrayCollection is a matter of where your coding/application priorities are: Do you need performance/do you have many items? -> Array is perhaps what you are looking for. Do you need short/quick coding, easier integrateable with flex objects? -> ArrayCollection might be the way to go.

**Further Reading**

[Some Differences explained](http://blog.flexdevelopers.com/2009/03/flex-basics-arraycollection.html)

[ArrayCollection Reference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/mx/collections/ArrayCollection.html)

[The filter function in action](http://weblog.mrinalwadhwa.com/2007/07/07/flex-tip-of-the-day-filterfunction-for-real-time-filtering-of-data/)

Comment: Also, some further food for thought for you: Did you know String is a flex class? It's not a primitive. I figured that out quite late.

Comment: That's a new info for me. Thanks for sharing that.

Comment: @FlorianMertens, String is neither a complex value, nor a Flex class. It's an Actionscript primitive. Check the documentation: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f9c.html

Comment: @AI_Birdy That's exactly my point. I was so strongly convinced that String is a primitive as well, and then check this: [String  - AS3](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/String.html). I _think_ that the flex framework overrides the Primitive with it's own class. This might not be true for non-flex frameworks, perhaps.